# How to track performance of different page templates in google analytics?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, wordpress-theming, analytics

If possible, how can you track different page templates / theme files individually in google analytics?

For example in wordpress you have these theme files:

```
single.php
category.php
custom-post-type.php 
page.php
```

How to track the performance of all page views that are shared by the same theme file? Say you have 100 pages that use single.php you want to see the average performance of that template instead of the individual page performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what sort of presentation you prefer, but content groups should be the preferred method. In general I would divide strategies into two buckets:

**Step by step analysis**
This is the easier, yet not so comfortable way. You would just search for the different themes in the *Behavior - Site Content - All Pages* view and check their metrics one-by-one. 
Alternatively you could use custom segments based on landing pages, page or content group to make the same search available through (almost) all reports. but again you wouldn't be able to compare them side-by-side and this should only be used if you don't have enough time for other solutions (see below).

**Direct analysis**
The obvious way would be to use [Content groups](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en) as a dimension and then set up custom reports e.g. These dimensions are built for your sort of analysis.
You could also use [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) (remember, you only have 20 of those in free Analytics). You would then either do a [data import](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport?hl=en) (where you join on the URL of the site and add an additional string indicating the theme) or insert code to your pages to indicate the theme directly.
Once you're done with this, you can design a custom report to compare the aggregated dimensions next to each other.

Again, Content Groups are likely the best method, as they're specifically designed for this, viewable as primary dimension in content reports and easy to set up.